# How to wrap procedural algorithms in OOP language

Tags: scala, oop

I have to implement an algorithm which fits perfectly to the procedural design approach. It has no relations with some data structure, it just takes couple of objects, bunch of control parameters and performs complicated operations on them, including creating and modifying intermediate temporal data, subroutines calls, many cpu-intensive data transformations. The algorithm is too specific to include in either parameter object as method.

What is idiomatic way to wrap such algorithms in an OOP language? Define static object with static method that performs calculation? Define class that takes all algorithm parameters as constructor arguments and have `result` method to return result? Any other way?

If you need more specifics, I'm writing in scala. But any general OOP approach is also applicable.

Comment: Especially in scala, it's trivial to create an `object` with function definitions that implement a procedural algorithm. Yes, it's essentially `static`, on the class that needs the algorithm or on a helper class.

Comment: static objects are easy to declare in other languages too. But I'm curious is that way to organize algorithms is suitable for an OOP languages. I'm curios if there are common design patters for such cases that I'm not aware of

Comment: Sure it is, why would you think it's not suitable?

Comment: It looks ugly. My intuitions says no-no, but I could not grasp what is the actual problem with such approach.

Comment: Can you show us the code? Or maybe you want to post it to [codereview.SE].

Answer (score 3):

A static method (or a method on a singleton object in the case of Scala -- which I'm just gonna call a static method because that's the most common terminology) can work perfectly fine and is probably the most common approach to this.

There's some reasons to use other approaches, but they aren't strictly necessary and I'd avoid them unless you actually need an advantage that they give. The reason for this is because static methods are the simplest (if least versatile) approach.

Using a non-static method can be useful because you can then utilize design patterns like the factory pattern. For example, you might have an `Operator` class with a method `evaluate`. Now you could have different factories create different `Operator`s so that you can swap your algorithm on the fly. Perhaps a calculator might have an `AddOperatorFactory`, `MultiplyOperatorFactory` and so on. Obviously this requires that you are able to instantiate an object that represents the algorithm. Of course, you could just pass a function around directly, as Scala and many other languages allow. Classes allow for inheritance, though, which opens the doors for some design patterns and, well, you're asking about OOP, not Scala specifically.

Also useful is the ability to have state with an object. With static methods, your only options for retaining state are either having global state (ew) or making the user of the static methods keep track of this state (more work for the users). With an instance of an object, you can keep that state inside the instance. For example, if your algorithm is a graph search, perhaps you'd want to allow resuming a search after you find the first match (which obviously requires storing state).

It's not much harder to have to do `new MyAlgorithm().doStuff()` instead of `MyAlgorithm.doStuff()`, so if in doubt, I would err on the side of avoiding static methods if you think you'll need the functionality that having an instance offers.

Comment: I was thinking about strange things. Like gathering arguments in some POD class. And applying this arguments. And other unnecessary complications the code look more like OOP